# PYTHON Nonetype object has no attribute .get() tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

This has come up before but no other solutions have worked for me thus far.
I have this code

```
userINP = Entry(root, width=25, bg ="White").place(x=120,y=100)
```

when I try userINP.get() I get

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Like I said i've looked at many other posts about this but no solutions work

Comment: Well it looks like the creation of `Entry()` is not working because you are getting a None value back. But without knowing any of the variables you are passing to it there's very little anyone can do to help debug it.

Comment: how is root initialized? only one line snippet with a undeclared variable is not enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.place()` method does *not* return a reference to the object. It is *not* a "*chaining method*". It simply alters the place and returns `None`, as is described in the [documentation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_place.htm).

You should call the `.place()` method after calling the constructor (and setting a reference to the `Entry`), like:

```
userINP = Entry(root, width=25, bg ="White")
userINP.place(x=120,y=100)
userINP.get(...)
```

Comment: Ah thanks, this worked, I thought putting .place on the same line would help to make the code shorter and I didn't think it would make a difference on how the code would work